# Is a Sensitivity-Specificity curve equal to a horizontally flipped ROC?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, sensitivity-specificity

So I need to plot a Sensitivity-Specificity curve. Since ROCs represent TPR (sensitivity) against FPR (or 1 - Specificity), can I just plot TPR against 1 - FPR as in the code below to obtain a Sens-Spec curve?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

...

fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
spec = 1 - fpr

#first plot (ROC)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(spec,tpr)

#second plot (Sens-Spec?)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(spec,tpr)
```

I plotted the results and compared it to the actual ROC, but I'm not sure if this is a correct way to do it or if I'm missing something.
[image: ROC and Sens-Spec]

Comment: ROC = sensitivity vs. 1 - specificity.  So sens vs spec is just flipped for one axis.   Neither ROC nor sens vs spec are relevant because they make the error of transposed conditionals; each point is a conditional probability that conditions on what is unknown to compute the probability of what is _already known_.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thank you. That's what I was thinking but needed someone to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `pROC` package in `R` even writes the x-axis this way.

[image]

```r
library(pROC)
set.seed(2023)
n <- 1000
p <- rbeta(N, 1, 1)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p)
r <- pROC::roc(y, p)
plot(r)
```

[The Frank Harrell in the comments has an interesting blog post about how sensitivity and specificity might be less useful than one might hope.](https://www.fharrell.com/post/backwards-probs/) Briefly, they condition on the unknown to predict the known.